# Drawing multiple rectangles using for loops in C

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop

I wrote a program in C which gets height and width or rectangle, and prints it like this:
The first border contains the letter a, the second border the letter b, the third border the letter c and so on.

It should look something like this:

```
aaaaaa 
abbbba 
abccba 
abccba
abbbba 
aaaaaa
```

code:

```
int height, width, letter=97, counter; //ascii value for a
int i, j;

scanf("%d%d", &height, &width);

for (i=1 ; i <= height ; i++)
{
    for (j=1 ; j <= width ; j++)
    {
            if (i == 1 || i == height || j == 1 || j == width)
                printf("%c", letter);
            else
            {
                if (i == 1+1 || i == height-1 || j == 1+1 || j == width-1)  
                    printf("%c", letter+1);                                 
                else
                    printf("%c", letter+1+1);
            }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

system("pause");
```

Sadly, I can't manage to find a way how to make the if loop work multiple times. I can only type it the amount of times I want.
how can I make a "counter" variable which runs the else of the if multiple times, so I can make more letters?

I try to make a counter variable that will work on the if statement instead of putting `i == 1+1` it will be `i == 1+counter`

Comment: "...make the `if` loop work...." `if` is not a loop.And [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27076695/draw-a-rectangle-made-with-printf-function-consisted-of-inner-frames) might help you...

Comment: `if` its a statement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need more than two loops to do this (the following is untested but should give you the idea):

```
for (i = 1; i <= height ; i++) {
   for (j = 1; j <= width ; j++) {
      printf("%c", min4(i - 1, j - 1, height - i, width - j) + 'a');
   }
}
```

Here, `min4` is a function that returns the smallest of its four arguments.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Can you show me another way to solve this without min4 function? We're not allowed to use it.